# Can we get an easy way to filter out status tags in MSO on the tag page?

Tags: feature-request

I can type `feature-request -status-declined -status-bydesign -status-completed` on the address line once I'm there, but is there no easier way? Statuses are a special concept and really only apply to things like feature and bugs. And it would be nice to easily switch between statuses when looking at these tags.

1. I don't generally want to see declined features, when I'm looking at features to see what's in the wind.
2. But if a feature occurs to me, I don't want to pester the developers with a request that they've already said no to as a concept. So being able to see declined features is a good thing here.

(I've recently dealt with a similar thing in one of my projects: general tagging scheme vs. an evolving specialized concept getting dumped into the GTS--which oddly enough was a sort of *status*. So I can appreciate the evolving case.)

- I have them in my ignore tags.

  ---

  **UPDATE:** I edited this whole post based on Jeff Atwood's clarification.

Comment: Belongs on meta-meta-stackoverflow... just kidding ;)

Answer (score 1):

see here

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/

also, you can turn ignored to invisible via your prefs tab on your user page

Ah, your REAL request is for tag filters to apply on the tag page itself. I see. We have actually implemented this, so try typing

> example.com/questions/tagged/feature-request -status-~

in the address bar. Note that we have some fairly strict rules around what we'll expand using the ~ expansion wildcard. It works on both "ends" but must have at least 4 characters to expand from.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting the questions to be hidden from you, you could add them to your ignored tags list couldn't you?