# “My sites” link on the top bar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, stackexchange-2.0, menu-bar

Can we have a "my sites" dropdown next to the "Stackexchange" dropdown on the topbar that lists all the sites the user is registered with? Or maybe an additional "tab" on the existing menu? Or even a replacement for the "all sites" tab. It would be really convenient to jump from one site to another.

Posted on meta.stackoverflow based on feedback on the [meta.stackexchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6566/my-sites-link-on-the-top-bar).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tab showing only "my sites" in the StackExchange global inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69047/tab-showing-only-my-sites-in-the-stackexchange-global-inbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It would be really convenient to jump from one site to another.

Use bookmarks.  Most browsers provide some sort of bookmark toolbar and bookmark folders: keep all your favorite SE sites in one folder on that toolbar.  This even lets you be signed up at a SE site without it being one you want cluttering up your quick-jump list!

Added bonus: make the bookmark to a specific page within the site that you visit most: for Meta (this site) I see active questions, for SO I see unanswered questions, I have one each for Ask Ubuntu and Meta Ask Ubuntu, but only Programmers without its meta, and so forth.  There's no way another dropdown in the SE bar can reach this level of customization.

Comment: If I'm registered with an SE site, I want it on the list...it won't cause clutter. And I think chrome/chromium's spoiled me. I want as much actual viewing space as possible. I just have the tabs and the one-line toolbar showing. The bookmarks are hidden too. But to be practical, I believe it _is_ much easier for me to set things up the way you suggested than for the SE programmers to add this feature to the site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just tossing this out there in case you are not aware it exists:

It is a few more clicks, but you *can* view your related accounts in your profile.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/145605?tab=accounts